# What is the best approach to load multiple excel files that are on NAS folder using IICS?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics-di, iics-mi

I have 50+ excel files on NAS folder that I would like to load to my `S3` bucket using `IICS`. Each file has different column names and number. For loading files.

I am using File ingestion task, to be specific "Filelist" as my source object. For Directory I am specifying my NAS folder path. For the option "Input file list path" I am specifying filelist.txt because this file contains path for multiple file. After running file ingestion task only one file is getting loaded into `S3` bucket.

Not sure what is the issue ? I was wondering if there is another approach to load multiple files using single taskflow ?

I am new to `IICS` so any help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For file transfer tasks try using IICS Mass Ingestion (Files) See the details on [Informatica website](https://www.informatica.com/products/cloud-integration/ingestion-at-scale.html) - just make sure to scroll down and choose File Ingestion.

When creating an MI task you choose source, file name pattern and target. MI task will transfer all the files with names matching the pattern. It can be scheduled, based on File Listener, and more.

Comment: Thanks Maciejg. I am currently using File ingestion task following this link ->https://thinketl.com/indirect-file-loading-in-iics/ The issue I am facing is creating a filelist, and in the section Guidelines for creating filelist it is mentioned that "Every path must be location to the secure Agent". I am not sure how to change the path of secure Agent ? Do I need to change the Home Directory Path or Do I need to chanage Working Directory Path of secure agent ?

Comment: The instructions refer to loading DATA from multiple files. NOT transferring the files. What you've described in original question as the goal is to transfer the files. So you have 50+ files on NAS and you want 50+ files on S3 - that's what Mass Ingestion is for. Using the approach described in the article will lead to loading contents from 50+ file to one, single target. Well... it would - but it will most likely fail for some other reasons. So long story short: don't follow that guide for your scenario. Use Mass Ingestion.

Comment: I am using File Listener approach. I created the file listener, and it is recognizing the the arrival of new file. However, it is not triggering the Mass Ingestion task associated with it. I added File Listener to the Schedule portion of the MI task. Any clue as to why this occur or am I missing something ?

Comment: There can na lots of issues with File Listener. Try scheduling first. If that works, try FL again. In case of issues share your setup details.